# How does $Mor(V,W)$ becomes a vector bundle and what are the transition functions of it?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $p_1:V\rightarrow X$ and $p_2:W\rightarrow X$ be two algebraic vector bundle over a variety $X$ of rank $n$ and $m$ respectively. Let's say $\{U_i,f_i\}$ and $\{U_i,g_i\}$ are trivializations for the vector bundles $V$ and $W$ respectively.

We define, $Mor(V,W)=\amalg_{x\in X}Hom(V_x,W_x)$.

Let $p:Mor(V,W)\rightarrow X$ be defined by $Hom(V_x,W_x)\rightarrow x$

The next step is to define local trivialization
(i.e. we need to define a map from $\phi_i:p^{-1}(U_i)\rightarrow U_i\times GL(nm, \mathbb{C})$ such that $proj\circ\phi_i=p$, where $proj: U_i\times GL(nm, \mathbb{C})\rightarrow U_i$ is the projection map)

Notice that, $p^{-1}(U_i)=\amalg_{x\in U_i}Hom(V_x,W_x)$

The map $\phi_i:\amalg_{x\in U_i}Hom(V_x,W_x)\rightarrow U_i\times GL(nm, \mathbb{C})$ can be defined as $Hom(V_x,W_x)\rightarrow x\times \text{The matrix correspinding to the map from}$ $V_x$  to  $W_x$.

But I have a feeling that the definition of should involve $f_i$ and $g_i$ (the local trivializaions for $V$ and $W$). Also, there is no guarantee that the matrix corresponding to the map form $V_x$ to $W_x$ will be non-singular, and the map I defined will not be well-defined.

My main aim is to write down the transition functions for the vector bundle $Mor(V,W)$ But I am stuck far before that in giving a vector bundle structure to $Mor(V,W)=\amalg_{x\in X}Hom(V_x,W_x)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is defined using transition functions $f_{ij} : U_i \cap U_j \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, thought of as acting on $\mathbb{C}^n$, and $W$ is defined using transition functions $g_{ij} : U_i \cap U_j \to GL_m(\mathbb{C})$, thought of as acting on $\mathbb{C}^m$ then the hom bundle $[V, W]$ is defined using transition functions

$$T \mapsto g_{ij} T f_{ij}^{-1}$$

thought of as acting on $[\mathbb{C}^n, \mathbb{C}^m]$.

Similarly, the tensor product bundle $V \otimes W$ is defined using transition functions $f_{ij} \otimes g_{ij} : U_i \cap U_j \to GL_{nm}(\mathbb{C})$, thought of as acting on $\mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^m$.

Comment: What is $T$ in the answer?

Comment: @Babai: $T$ is any linear map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^m$.